# add/remove bootstrap rows w/js

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I have a form in a page created with Bootstrap, and what I would like to do is the ability to add and remove a row in the table (made with the divs).

**HTML:**

```
<form name="modulo" id="form1">
    <br/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label for="fld1">Label:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" name="fld1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label for="fld2">Label2:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" name="fld2">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addnewrow()" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" name="fldA0">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" name="fldB0">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" name="fldC0">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" name="fldD0">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="button" disabled="disabled" value="remove" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
var num=1;
function addnewrow(){
    if(document.createElement && document.getElementById && document.getElementsByTagName) {

        var oTr=document.createElement("div");
        var oTd1=document.createElement("div");
        var oTd2=document.createElement("div");
        var oTd3=document.createElement("div");
        var oTd4=document.createElement("div");
        var oTd5=document.createElement("div");
        var fldA=document.createElement("INPUT");
        var fldB=document.createElement("INPUT");
        var fldC=document.createElement("INPUT");
        var fldD=document.createElement("INPUT");
        var oButt=document.createElement("INPUT");

        oTr.classList.add('row');
        oTd1.classList.add('col');
        oTd2.classList.add('col');
        oTd3.classList.add('col');
        oTd4.classList.add('col');
        oTd5.classList.add('col');
        fldA.setAttribute("type","text");
        fldA.setAttribute("name","fldA"+num);

        fldB.setAttribute("type","text");
        fldB.setAttribute("name","fldB"+num);

        fldC.setAttribute("type","text");
        fldC.setAttribute("name","fldC"+num);

        fldD.setAttribute("type","text");
        fldD.setAttribute("name","fldD"+num);

        oButt.setAttribute("type","button");
        oButt.setAttribute("value","remove");


        if(oButt.attachEvent) oButt.attachEvent('onclick',function(e){rimuovi(e);})
        else if(oButt.addEventListener) oButt.addEventListener('click',function(e){removerow(e);},false)


        oTd1.appendChild(fldA);
        oTd2.appendChild(fldB);
        oTd3.appendChild(fldC);
        oTd4.appendChild(fldD);
        oTd5.appendChild(oButt);
        oTr.appendChild(oTd1);
        oTr.appendChild(oTd2);
        oTr.appendChild(oTd3);
        oTr.appendChild(oTd4);
        oTr.appendChild(oTd5);

        document.getElementById('form1').lastElementChild.after(oTr);

        num++
    }
}

function removerow(e){

    if(document.removeChild && document.getElementById && document.getElementsByTagName) {
        if(!e) e=window.event;
        var srg=(e.target)?e.target:e.srcElement;

        while(srg.tagName!="div" && !(srg.classList?.contains('row'))){srg=(srg.parentNode)?srg.parentNode:srg.parentElement}

        var tb=document.getElementById('form1').lastElementChild;    <--- ERROR

        tb.removeChild(srg);
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand whats the point of this condition right at the start of your function to add a new row `if(document.createElement && document.getElementById && document.getElementsByTagName) {`

Comment: What is the expected result and how is your code differing from that?

Comment: `var tb=document.getElementById('form1').lastElementChild;    <--- ERROR`  should be : `var tb=document.getElementById('form1');`